# Switch case skipping input and going straight to first if statement

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have an assignment due for a class and I have to use contains() and toUpperCase(). I am not allowed to use loops or arrays. I know a loop would make this a whole lot easier, but I have to do it the long way. Also, I am using Eclipse for this class if that matters.

I run the program for this case and it skips right over my `bookSearch = input.nextLine();` and just displays the first if statement but with no output after `System.out.println("You searched for: " + bookSearch.toUpperCase());` and displays bookOne. My problem is that I need to be able to get input for bookSearch or have some way to compare it to the 3 string variables books using contains().

I have tried adjusting how I present the string bookSearch and reorganizing where it is, I've tried running it without the else-if statements as well and that also results in skipping over the user input and just ending the case. I am honestly not even sure if the else-if statements work yet because I cannot get input for bookSearch.

I have only included the first case so ignore that there are 2 other options for the switch.

```
public class DemoMathCharString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("~~ Hello and welcome to your Local Library Portal. Please select from one of the following options. ~~");
            System.out.println("1.) Library Catalog\n2.) Library Visitors Statistics\n3.) Library Books Statistics");
        
        int option = input.nextInt(); //get user's menu selection
        
        switch(option) { 
        case 1: 
            String bookOne = "The Telltale Heart";
            String bookTwo = "Wuthering Heights";
            String bookThree = "A Court of Thorns and Roses"; 
            String bookSearch;
            
            System.out.println("Please enter your search for this library catalog. Please note that search is case sensitive.\nThe books shown after your search are the books we have available for borrowing at this time.");
            bookSearch = input.nextLine();
            if (bookOne.contains(bookSearch)) {
                System.out.println("You searched for: " + bookSearch.toUpperCase());
                System.out.println("We have the following book available to be borrowed: " + bookOne);
            }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) - this answer is clear and concise https://stackoverflow.com/a/7056782/857132

Comment: When you call scanner.nextInt() it retrieves the next number it finds. Calling scanner.nextLine() retrieves any remaining input until it encounters a new line character which happens when the person presses enter. Try this out by inputting "1 Heart". That should end up working in the following code. The solution is skipping the line after getting the int.

Comment: Nothing to do with [tag:switch-statement], [tag:contains], or [tag:if-statement] whatsoever.